AWS security group to allow JDBC traffic AND disallow psql traffic
I have an ECS container which runs a Java app. I have a database not hosted in AWS. I want to be able to run queries only from JDBC connections and NOT psql connections. For instance, if someone has access only to my ECS container I don't want them to be able to install psql and run arbitrary queries. How can I create an aws security group that allows JDBC traffic AND disallows psql traffic?

I can't see how this would be possible.  Both use port 5432 by default to connect.  If someone has access to your container and can install software you've got much bigger problems than psql.

You're right, probably can't distinguish the traffic at the transport layer. BUT my understanding is that they're different at the application layer. So, I was wondering if there's way to block traffic going to different applications.

There's no way to do this with a security group, since it only looks at the port. Security groups don't examine the contents of the traffic. If your understanding is the traffic is different in some way between JDBC and psql then it would help if you included the details of that difference in your question, or linked to it at least, so that we might be able to point to something that would work. My understanding was that the traffic is not different in any substantial way.

For example, http, dns, sftp are application layer protocols as opposed to tcp which is a transport layer protocol. AWS allows adding security rules for HTTP traffic only. So, I was wondering if there was a way to distinguish JDBC traffic from psql traffic based on the application layer protocol they use

Perhaps Opensnitch would do close to what you want to do.  It would be installed on the ECS.  But, once again, it sounds like your ECS users have root so they can promptly uninstall it.  And you'd have to be super familiar with the protocol PostgreSQL is using over the wire to be able to block the correct traffic without false positives.
